# Error Page Not Found. Error 404 wordpress at homepage

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I'm new to wordpress. I use xampp and set wordpress in careers forder, I imported from file sql, but after when enter website it being 404 error.

When I go to the admin page with address https://local-careers.jv-it.com.vn/careers/wp-admin, I get an error Object not found.

Does anyone know what's wrong with it and how to fix it?

Comment: use developer tools in your browser to see which URL is throwing the error

Comment: why did you use the `localhost` tag?

Comment: This web on my localhost

Comment: i found the reason in wp_options table the url to change is the same as your current url.